# How to start for wopi protocol to Integrate with Office for the web? using azure to deploy wopi host

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, ms-wopi, office-online-server

I have a vuejs application in which I want to offer editing documents with office for web. I have looked into official wopi documentation and some existing wopi implementation. The official wopi documentation lacks "How to start". There are few queries I want to clear before moving forward

Infrastructure: I have vuejs application, .NET 5 api at backend and I use azure environment for deployment (azure app service), documents are stored in blob storage. My first question is regarding white-listing the wopi host. If I understand the documentation correctly, vuejs will be wopi client and .net core api will be wopi host?. and then I have to white-list api domain?

Secondly, in [microsoft code sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/officedev/pnp-wopi/pnp-wopi/) they said `You cannot simply clone and run this sample locally....localhost probably won't work`. I want to ask in order to test my code do I have to deploy it every time I make changes?  if so how will I debug it?

Lastly, I read people mentioning Office Online Server 2016 is required to deploy and run wopi as mentioned [here](https://github.com/petrsvihlik/WopiHost). Will this not work with azure deployment?

Additionally I have already signed up for [Cloud Storage Partner Program](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/cloud-storage-partner-program)

Answer (score 1):

Let's start from the end.

> Lastly, I read people mentioning Office Online Server 2016 is required to deploy and run wopi as mentioned here.

You can either deploy the Office Online Server or use Office Online via the Cloud Storage Partner Program (CSPP).

> vuejs will be wopi client and .net core api will be wopi host?

No, Office Online Server or Office Online via CSPP will always play the role of the "WOPI client". Your .NET backend will be "WOPI host" and your Vue.js app will be serving the [WOPI host page/frame](https://wopi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/hostpage.html) (the word "host" in this context is not related to WOPI host).

> and then I have to white-list api domain?

The way I understand it is that you need to whitelist mainly the domain of the WOPI host page (Vue.js app in your case). But it's also required for your WOPI host (.NET backend) in case it runs on a subdomain. Read more [here](https://wopi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_test_ship/settings.html#wopi-domain-allow-list).

> Secondly, in microsoft code sample they said You cannot simply clone and run this sample locally....localhost probably won't work. I want to ask in order to test my code do I have to deploy it every time I make changes? if so how will I debug it?

No, you don't. Make sure your WOPI host is publicly accessible from the internet - e.g. public IP, [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) with reserved domain ([for as little as $5](https://ngrok.com/pricing)). And make sure you add the IP/domain to the [Test environment](https://wopi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_test_ship/environments.html#test-environment) white list. Then you can debug it locally.

> Will this not work with azure deployment?
> If you choose to use Office Online Server 2016, you can deploy it wherever you want. If you deploy it to Azure, make sure you configure your vnet to be only accessible by your apps/resources.

Comment: thank you for the clarification. I want to ask for the whitelist part. my web app is deployed on domain1 and api is on domain2. so i have to whitelist both domains?

Comment: and both web and api are deployed on azure appservice, so do I have to configure vnet for azure appservice as well?

Comment: @rocky it's taken me a few hours of research to figure out the exact definition of WOPI Host and WOPI Client, thanks for mentioning that here.